# Triple Loop to delete Empty Folders

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete those folders that are empty with a triple loop.

The order is:
 1. Enter into the Main Folder.
 2. Check the first encountered folder
 3. Check the first subFolder of the main folder.
 4. If that subFolder contains another folder, enter in this subSubFolder
 5. If it is the last folder and doesn't contain anything, the program deletes it.
 5.1 If the folder contains something (a file, excel, pdf, doesn't matter) just go to the next subSubFolder.
 6. And goes on until there's no empty folders.

Basically the code must leave untouched the folders that contains a File.

But i don't know why the code doesn't continue and just stop without deleting the empty ones.

This is the Folder Structure:
[Folder Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWa6f.png)

And this is the code i'm using.:

```
Sub recursiveDeleting()
    Dim sFldr As Object
    Dim ssFldr As Object
    Dim sssFldr As Object
    Dim fs

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFound = False
    ssFound = False
    sssFound = False

    flPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    YearPath = flPath & "2017\"
    FARFIpath = YearPath & "\FAR_FI\"

    For Each sFldr In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject").GetFolder(FARFIpath).SubFolders
        For Each ssFldr In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject").GetFolder(sFldr).SubFolders
            For Each sssFldr In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemobject").GetFolder(ssFldr).SubFolders
                If Dir(sssFldr & "\*.*") = "" Then
                    RmDir (sssFldr)
                Else
                    sssFound = True
                End If

                If sssFound = True Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next sssFldr

        If fs.FolderExists(ssFldr) = "" Then
            RmDir (ssFldr)
        Else
            ssFound = True
        End If
        If ssFound = True Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Next ssFldr
    If Dir(sFldr, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        RmDir (sFldr)
        sFound = True
    End If

   If sFound = True Then
      Exit For
   End If
 Next sFldr
End Sub
```

Thanks for your time and have a good day!

Comment: Could be because RmDir doesn't use parens.  Try RmDir "MYDIR" or RmDir sssFldr

Comment: @mooseman the parens are merely forcing their contents to be evaluated as a value and force-passed `ByVal` to the invoked procedure; this (bad) habit of introducing extraneous parentheses everywhere can cause compile errors (when multiple arguments are specified), or run-time errors (when parameter is an object reference), but most of the time it has no effect whatsoever, other than that weird whitespace between the procedure identifier and its argument list. IOW, I doubt it's related to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, tested working (it will delete the root folder as well if it's empty afterwards. It can be mind blogging if you are to trace back the recursive code.

Sample - only a blank text file in highlighted folder (all others has no files).
[image: SampleFolderStructure]

```
Option Explicit

Private oFSO As Object

Sub DeleteEmptyFolder()
    Dim oRootFDR As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oRootFDR = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Test\mount") '<--- Change to your root folder
    If DeleteEmptyFolderOnly(oRootFDR) Then
        oRootFDR.Delete
    End If
    Set oRootFDR = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Private Function DeleteEmptyFolderOnly(ByRef oFDR As Object) As Boolean
    Dim bDeleteFolder As Boolean, oSubFDR As Object
    bDeleteFolder = False
    ' Recurse into SubFolders
    For Each oSubFDR In oFDR.SubFolders
        If DeleteEmptyFolderOnly(oSubFDR) Then
            Debug.Print "Delete", oSubFDR.Path ' Comment for production use
            oSubFDR.Delete
        End If
    Next
    ' Mark ok to delete when no files and subfolders
    If oFDR.Files.Count = 0 And oFDR.SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
        bDeleteFolder = True
    End If
    DeleteEmptyFolderOnly = bDeleteFolder
End Function
```

After the code executed, Folders remained are:
[image: FolderAfterwards]

And the immediate window shows the folders that are deleted:
[image: DebugPrintOutput]

Comment: Mon Ami! This is the answer i've been looking for at least 2 days! Thank you very much.
I'm still new at VBA, so i still don't know how to use functions yet, only the basic commands as you can see.
Again, thank you very much for your time! It's very appreciated.

Comment: Very helpful and it does work as described. Thank you.